# The webView is nil in iOS 8 but it's not nil in iOS 9 using xib

Tags: ios, webview

### Why the webView is nil in iOS 8 but not in iOS 9?

and how should I use webview in iOS 8?
Here is the code (swift 2.2)

in a `viewController` class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.webView?.delegate = self   // without '?' in iOS 8 crash
                                    // in iOS 9 not crash
    
    // debug code
    if let webView = self.webView { // iOS 8 nil
        print("\(webView)")         // iOS 9 not nil
    }

    //...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How can you unwrap your webview when you declared it as UIWebView!

Comment: an implicitly unwrapped optional can still be nil; the compiler just won't force you to unwrap it when you use it and will give an unexpected nil exception if it is nil when you access it

Comment: I know an implicitly unwrapped optional can still be nil. I use the code just want to find out why in ios 8 is nil but ios 9 not. because when I set the  webview's delegate and title or others, it will crash(without '?') in ios 8,won't in ios 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com")


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.webView.delegate = self

    let req = NSURLRequest(URL : url!)
    self.webView.loadRequest(req)
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    print("start loading")
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    print("finish loading")
}

//...

}
```

like this, this code can run perfectly in iOS8 & iOS9

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webViewXib: UIWebView!
var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let _ = self.webViewXib {
    self.webView = self.webViewXib
    } else {
        self.webView = UIWebView()
        self.webView.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(self.webView!)
    }
    self.webView!.delegate = self    

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way how instantiate your View Controller, you are probably instantiating it as:

`MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init]`

With that you will not have the view ready in your viewDidLoad, instead you should try:

`MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:"MyViewController" bundle:nil]`